# Little Endian Mips operation

Tags: mips

I am struggling to understand what this block of mips instruction does. I want to find out what the register $t0 has after these instructions.

```
ori  $t0 $zero  0xA5C11000
addi $t1 $zero  0x10010000

sw   $t0  ($t1)
lb   $t0 1($t1)
sh   $t0 2($t1)
lw   $t0  ($t1)
```

I know that the registers $t0 and $t1 have A5C11000 and 10010000 in them. Then the sw command stores $t1 at the location of $t0. Lb then offsets $t1 by 1 and stores that at the location 10010001? I don't know what happens after this.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite: `sw` stores the contents of `$t0` at the address in `$t1`, i.e. `10010000`. `lb` loads a byte from address `$t1 + 1` into `$t0`.  `sh` stores a halfword (the lower 2 bytes of `$t0`) at address `$t1 +2`.

Try stepping through the code in the debugger to see what it does.